# ¿Cómo compilar y testear una libreria compartida C con meson?

Tags: c

Estoy realizando una libreria compartida en C que depende de GLib, la cual codifico con meson. Mi estructura de proyecto es la siguiente:

```
libreria-compartida
|--meson.build
|--include
|  |--meson.build
|  |--libcompartida
|  |  |--etiqueta
|  |  |  |--etiqueta.h
|
|--src
|  |--meson.build
|  |--etiqueta
|  |  |--etiqueta.c
|
|--test
|  |--meson.build
|  |--etiqueta.c
```

Mis archivos Meson son los siguientes; en orden descendente por el Arbol de proyecto:

### meson raíz:

```
project('libreria compartida', 'c', version: '0.0.1')

glib = dependency('glib-2.0')

encabezados = include_directories('include')

subdir('include')
subdir('src')
subdir('test')

pkg = import('pkgconfig')
pkg.generate(libraries: libcompartida,
            version: '0.0.1',
            name: 'libcompartida',
            filebase: 'libcompartida',
            description: 'Libreria compartida de prueba realizada en C')
```

### include/meson

```
install_subdir('libcompartida', install_dir: 'libcompartida')
```

### src/meson

```
libcompartida_sources = ['etiqueta/etiqueta.c']

libcompartida = shared_library('libcompartida',
                          libcompartida_sources,
                          include_directories: encabezados,
                          dependencies: glib,
                          install: true)
```

### test/meson

```
test_etiqueta = executable('test_etiqueta', 'etiqueta.c',
                          include_directories: encabezados,
                          link_with: libcompartida)
test('etiqueta test', test_etiqueta)
```

No muestro código porque no lo considero necesario, pero si a ustedes sí le parece, me comentan y lo publico. El código no es mucho, creo un objeto etiqueta utilizando GLib y GObject. Aunque en test enlazo la libreria, no utilizo el objeto etiqueta, en el test solo hago un `printf` para ver si la prueba es ejecutada.

Cuando intento compilar obtengo el siguente error:

```
Found runner: ['/usr/bin/ninja']
ninja: Entering directory .'
[1/3] Linking target src/libcompartida.so
FAILED: src/libcompartida.so 
cc  -o src/libcompartida.so src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -fPIC -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-soname,libcompartida.so /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so -Wl,--end-group
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_class_intern_init':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:11: referencia a g_type_class_peek_parent' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:11: referencia a g_type_class_adjust_private_offset' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_get_type_once':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:11: referencia a g_type_register_static_simple' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:11: referencia a g_type_add_instance_private' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_set_property':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:31: referencia a g_type_check_instance_cast' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:34: referencia a g_type_instance_get_private' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:39: referencia a g_value_dup_string' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:47: referencia a g_value_get_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:57: referencia a g_value_get_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:62: referencia a g_type_name' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:62: referencia a g_type_name' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_get_property':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:72: referencia a g_type_check_instance_cast' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:73: referencia a g_type_instance_get_private' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:77: referencia a g_value_set_string' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:81: referencia a g_value_set_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:85: referencia a g_value_set_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:89: referencia a g_type_name' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:89: referencia a g_type_name' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_constructor':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:96: referencia a g_type_check_class_cast' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_class_init':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:102: referencia a g_type_class_add_private' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:103: referencia a g_type_check_class_cast' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:110: referencia a g_param_spec_string' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:117: referencia a g_param_spec_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:124: referencia a g_param_spec_object' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: /directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:130: referencia a g_object_class_install_properties' sin definir
/usr/bin/ld: src/libcompartida.so.p/etiqueta_etiqueta.c.o: en la función a_etiqueta_init':
/directorio-proyecto/../src/etiqueta/etiqueta.c:134: referencia a g_type_instance_get_private' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Aunque comprendo lo que me dice el compilador no sé dónde tengo el error. Me complica mucho la compilación en C y C++, no logro entenderla.

Espero que puedan ayudarme mi problema.

Comment: Haz una prueba; si funciona te lo explico: por la `glib` como dependencia de `test_etiqueta`.

Comment: `g_type_class_peek_parent` que aparece en el error es una función que pertenece a la librería gobject y no glib, así que tambien tienes que agregarla como dependencia con `dependency('gobject-2.0')`